IN query using sequential scan when entries are more (Postgres)
I have created index on userID column, data type of this column is character varying(1000)

Case 1. when I am putting record 12 or less than 12 inside IN query

Query
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) SELECT * FROM users_8116 WHERE "userID" in ('4', '9678', '19036', '24930', '31669', '43604', '46754', '51422', '63743', '69826', '84860', '98225') 

QUERY PLAN
"Gather  (cost=53214.43..947715.53 rows=554610 width=3716) (actual time=7.833..8.004 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 2"
"  Workers Launched: 2"
"  Buffers: shared hit=55 read=5"
"  I/O Timings: shared read=3.953"
"  ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on users_8116  (cost=52214.43..891254.53 rows=231088 width=3716) (actual time=1.445..1.446 rows=0 loops=3)"
"        Recheck Cond: ((""userID"")::text = ANY ('{4,9678,19036,24930,31669,43604,46754,51422,63743,69826,84860,98225}'::text[]))"
"        Buffers: shared hit=55 read=5"
"        I/O Timings: shared read=3.953"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on user_userid_8116_index  (cost=0.00..52075.75 rows=554610 width=0) (actual time=4.057..4.057 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: ((""userID"")::text = ANY ('{4,9678,19036,24930,31669,43604,46754,51422,63743,69826,84860,98225}'::text[]))"
"              Buffers: shared hit=55 read=5"
"              I/O Timings: shared read=3.953"
"Settings: effective_cache_size = '1879920kB', jit = 'off'"
"Planning Time: 0.098 ms"
"Execution Time: 8.101 ms"


Case 2. when I am putting record more than 12 inside IN query

Query
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) SELECT * FROM users_8116 WHERE "userID" in ('4', '41', '9678', '19036', '24930', '31669', '43604', '46754', '51422', '63743', '69826', '84860', '98225')

QUERY PLAN
"Gather  (cost=1000.03..957253.58 rows=600827 width=3716) (actual time=51317.205..51319.302 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 2"
"  Workers Launched: 2"
"  Buffers: shared hit=96 read=838303"
"  I/O Timings: shared read=148403.770"
"  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on users_8116  (cost=0.03..896170.88 rows=250345 width=3716) (actual time=51312.410..51312.411 rows=0 loops=3)"
"        Filter: ((""userID"")::text = ANY ('{4,41,9678,19036,24930,31669,43604,46754,51422,63743,69826,84860,98225}'::text[]))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 3081165"
"        Buffers: shared hit=96 read=838303"
"        I/O Timings: shared read=148403.770"
"Settings: effective_cache_size = '1879920kB', jit = 'off'"
"Planning Time: 0.104 ms"
"Execution Time: 51319.331 ms"

Index definition
CREATE INDEX user_userid_8116_index
    ON public.users_8116 USING btree
    ("userID" COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

I do not want to do query with sequential scan, index should be used

Please provide EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) output.

Was that index created recently? If not then you should try recreating it and trying again. Indexes going out of date is not something that should happen... but it happens.

@Gimby Yes, I have created index recently (yesterday)

The fundamental problem seems to be that PostgreSQL thinks that there will be a lot of result rows, while really there are none.  What you should do is improve the estimates.  Try the following in turn:

See if recalculating statistics gives you better estimates:
ANALYZE users_8116;

If that does the trick, the problem is probably that PostgreSQL doesn't calculate statistics for this table often enough. Fix that with
ALTER TABLE users_8116 SET (autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.01);

or lower values if necessary.

Otherwise, the resolution of the statistics is probably too low. Try
SET default_statistics_target = 1000;
ANALYZE users_8116;

If that does the trick, persist the setting for the column:
ALTER TABLE users_8116 ALTER "userID" SET STATISTICS 1000;

Pick a value that is as low as possible — perhaps 500 will suffice.



Lowering random_page_costs also helps

@FrankHeikens Probably yes.
